# c# streamwriter close() not closing stream

Tags: c#

```
void Spausdinimas(AutomobiliuKonteineris miestai, 
                  string tekstas, 
                  bool stop, 
                  string failas)
{
    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(failas, stop))
    {
        writetext.WriteLine(tekstas);
        writetext.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < miestai.Count; i++)
        {
            writetext.WriteLine(miestai.GetCar(i));
        }

        writetext.WriteLine();
        writetext.Close();
    }
}
```

i don't know why but it is *not closing* the file and after re-debugging it *isn't overwritting*.

Comment: The `using` statement will dispose the object for you so you don't have to call `writetext.Close();`

Comment: `writetext.Close();` can be omitted. the `using` statement already closes it and calles the dispose method

Comment: im using bool stop and its true so it wont close by itself.

Comment: try wrapping  in `try`   `finally
{
   sr.Close();
}`

Comment: yes there must be something else wrong because as mentioned the using statement disposes of your writer. are you getting an error?

Comment: how do you know that it doesn't close?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Comment: im not getting, i just check the file where it writes and then i see that it just writting, not overwritting

Comment: @LukasVelička so the problem is that you don't want to append??

Comment: "im using bool stop and its true so it wont close by itself" - can you explain this a bit more? As far as I can see the bool you are using is purely being used to determine whether to overwrite or append to the file (`failas`). It has nothing to do with closing the file. Also other comments suggest that you are confused about it not overwriting when you expect it to and I'm wondering if you have misread the documentation... if `stop` is true then it will append your data to the file. if it is false it will overwrite it.

Comment: `I'm using bool stop and its true so it wont close by itself`  That parameter should be called `append` because that's what it controls.

Comment: yeah that bool stop, just cuz you call it stop, wont stop anything. the fact that its set to true in that method is why your file wont overwrite. its set to append. try it with stop set to false, i bet it overwrites.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the StreamWriter in a using statement, it will be disposed of indirectly. This is the MS documentation for it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).

As far as not overwriting the file, you are using the two parameter constructor. If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) the second parameter is a boolean for "Append" and I don't know if you are setting it to true or false, but that is why it isn't replacing it with a newer file.

Here are the changes I would recommend since I don't know exactly what you are trying to do:

```
void Spausdinimas(AutomobiliuKonteineris miestai, 
              string tekstas, 
              bool stop, 
              string failas)
{
  using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(failas))
  {
    writetext.WriteLine(tekstas);
    writetext.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < miestai.Count; i++)
    {
        writetext.WriteLine(miestai.GetCar(i));
    }

    writetext.WriteLine();
  }
}
```